# How to pass Django data to an external JS file?

Tags: javascript, python, django, python-2.7, django-views

I am working on a Django project. I would like to pass a data from Django's views.py into a javascript file, run the js function then render the return value into my html page. I am not using a form in this project. Can someone please guide me on how to approach this? Most answers I see here are currently outdated and I've tried different approaches with no luck. I am using Python v2.7. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

If your project is using [Jinja](http://jinja.pocoo.org) or some other templating engine you could try passing the data into the template.

Found this bit on [Writing your first Django app, part 3](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/intro/tutorial03/#write-views-that-actually-do-something) and tweaked it a bit.

```
def index(request):
    template = loader.get_template('app/index.html')
    my_data = ['whatever your data is']
    context = {
        'my_data': my_data,
    }
    return HttpResponse(template.render(context, request))
```

And in index.html

```
<html>
    <head>
        // import jQuery
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id='my_data_label'></div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var my_data = "{{ my_data }}"; // gets set by jinja
            $('.my_data_label').text(my_data);
            // do whatever with the data
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Not sure if this is exactly what you're looking for, but hope it helps.

Comment: OMG thanks! I forgot to pass "my_data" to a context. Do you know a way in which I can pass "my_data" into a .js file? Also, if I were to go this route, will it be a problem if I pass more than 1 variable? Thanks again! :)

Comment: See my comment above for using a variable with an external javascript file (spoiler: it's easy). There is certainly no limit to how many objects you use.

Answer (score 1):

It might a good idea to directly render the javascript data inside a `<script>` tag on the template for the page. If it is to be used in several pages, make sure to include it in the base template or import it using a include.

Your view might resemble a standard django view:

```
def detail(request, poll_id):
    try:
        p = Poll.objects.get(pk=poll_id)
    except Poll.DoesNotExist:
        raise Http404("Poll does not exist")
    return render(request, 'polls/detail.html', {'poll': p})
```

The template would have some added logic to build the javascript object:

```
<script>
var questionset = {
    {% for q in poll.question_set %}
        q.id : {
            "title": "{{ q.title }}",
            "score": {{ q.score }}
        }
        {% if not loop.last %},{% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
}
</script>
```

You now have a javascript object at your disposal in the template, that gets dynamically built from the data. You can use it as you please:

```
<script>
    function doSomething(questionset){
        ...
    }
</script>
```

There are ways to save your data to a javascript file, but bear in mind that this get cached by the client's browser. Not a good idea to have dynamic data in that.

Comment: My django skills are a bit rusty, so please double check my code before use. Any corrections are appreciated.

Comment: Hi Roy! Thanks for your comment. I will play around on this code and update you if there is anything :)

Comment: Roy, I am avoiding adding a <script> tag in my html file because my entire page consists of four graphs. Those four graphs are being rendered by javascript. That is why I have made 4 external javascript files that links to my html. Lets say I successfully stored "my_var" into my html file through <script> var a = "{{my_var}}" </script> how can I pass variable "a" to an external .js file?

Comment: @Marvin There are two ways: `1)` Make sure you put the custom `<script>` before the `<script>` that imports the external file. That way you can use the variable inside the external file. `2)` You make an extra `<script>` at the very bottom that calls the function from the external file, using the variable you provide.

Comment: @Marvin I would prefer the second method, as it keeps the external file cleaner. Those are usually meant for re-use.

Comment: In the code example I provided, the `function doSomething(myvar)` could easily be a function that you loaded from an external file.

Comment: How is this coming along? Is any of the answers helped you, consider accepting the answer, so others may benefit from your experience.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend [json_script](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#std:templatefilter-json_script)

Here is an example. My code in the views.py

```
def countymap(request):
    json_data = open('home/static/GEOJSON/NECounties2.geojson')
    countyData = json.load(json_data)
    return render(request, 'home/Countymap.html',
                  {'countyData': countyData})
```

On my HTML, I use json_script to get the data and assign an id to it. In addition, there is a separate Javascript file (let's call it Countymap)

```
<html>
blah blah blah
{{ countyData | json_script:"county-data" }}
<script type="text/javascript" src='{% static "js/Countymap.js" %}'></script>
<html>
```

Inside the Countymap javascript, use this to get the data

```
var countyData = JSON.parse(document.getElementById('county-data').textContent);
```

Hope it still helps

Comment: in this case the value countyData is show into template the idea is dont show this